# How long does PageSpeed Insights take to show results after optimizing website speed?

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

hi i have optimized my site for speed i would like to know how much time it will take PageSpeed Insights to show Core Web Vitals Assessment: Passed desktop shows Core Web Vitals Assessment: Passed. is there anything to do from my end
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR9K3.jpg

optimized website for speed and fixed few technical issues

Answer (score 2):

PageSpeed Insights shows two sources of data:

At the top is the "Discover what your real users are experiencing" section which shows data from the [Chrome User Experience Report (or CrUX for short)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/).

This is collected over the previous last 28-days:

[image: PageSpeed Insights screenshot with the 28-days highlighted]

It also shows the 75th percentile of data to give a number that the majority of your users experienced. So you need to wait for at least 75% of your page views over the last 28 days to experience any performance improvements before you see it reflected in this. All else being equal, if traffic is similar each day, then you should see it starts to take effect 3/4 of the way through this period so from about 21 or 22 days. The full effect will not be completed until the 28 days have passed after which all your page views should be on your new code (assuming no caching issues on your site).

You can click the "Expand view" button on the right to see more data:

[image: LCP expanded view]

This indicated the number of page views in each section. That can be useful to check over the next few days to ensure the percentage of pages in each category and moving in the direction you want them (e.g. you start to see a higher percentage of pages in the "Good" category) to even if the 75th Percentile figure will not move for a number of weeks.

I've written more on the subject here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/complete-guide-measure-core-web-vitals/

The second section on the Lighthouse test below this ("Diagnose performance issues"). This is run for each run, so if you optimised your site's performance then you should immediately see improvement's here by rerunning.

Answer (score 0):

you can hover those (?) tooltip button. [image]

it says 28 days for collecting data. I think we don't have to do anything